# Se borra el valor de una variable cuando vuelvo a iniciar el form

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo la siguiente duda, no la clasificaría como problema; en estos casos ¿cómo se manejan estos datos?:

1. Creo una clase con su respectivas variables.
2. Luego en un formulario creo el objeto de la clase y se le da un valor Ej.: 10.000
3. cuando vuelvo a abrir el formulario (no me salgo de la aplicación, solamente cierro el form y me voy a otro que es el form principal), el
   valor es 0, no se guarda el valor.

La pregunta sería tipo: *Almacenar valor de variables al volver a un formulario.*

¿Qué se hace en este caso? o para ese tipo de situaciones ¿qué se maneja?

```
 internal class ClaseCancha // Esta es la clase que creamos 
    {
        
        private double Precio = 0;  //Precio de las canchas
        private bool[] Reservas = new bool[20]; //Matriz De reservas 

        public double precio //Asignadores 
            {

            get
                { return Precio; }
            set { Precio = value; }        

            }
```

La de abajo es el form desde donde llamamos a la otra clase

```
public partial class Form_Propiedades : Form
    {
        ClaseCancha ValorCancha = new ClaseCancha(); //Creamos objeto 
        public Form_Propiedades()
        {
            
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void BtnGuardarPequeña_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ValorCancha.precio = Convert.ToDouble(TxCanchaPequeña.Text); //Asignamos el valor de la cancha a la clase

                 //Asignamos al label el valor de la variable y luego la pasamos a datos numerico y decimales 
                LbValorResultadoPequeña.Text = Convert.ToString(ValorCancha.precio.ToString("N1"));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Porfavor Coloque SOLO NUMEROS :D ");
            }
        }

        private void Form_Propiedades_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          


               LbValorResultadoPequeña.Text = Convert.ToString(ValorCancha.precio); //Se deberia de cargar el valor 
que se  pone PERO SOLO APARECE 0 , NO SE GUARDAN LOS 
VALORES QUE SE ASIGNARON ;(((
            }
        }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los forms, como todos los objetos, son instancias de una clase.

Por lo tanto, como otros objetos, al desaparecer (por ejemplo, cuando lo cierran) pierden todos sus datos.

Si uds quieren retener un objeto, hay varias estrategias, dependiendo de como este estructurado el sistema:

- guardar los datos en una base de datos
- devolver un objeto a quien llamo
- tener objetos globales, o en una clase padre que no se borra nunca (por ejemplo en el form principal)
- pasar una referencia del objeto desde el padre para que el hijo lo modifique

Todas estas estrategias (y seguro hay mas) se pueden usar indistintamente, algunas mucho mas recomendable que otras, dependiendo el programa.

Lo principal a entender son dos cosas:

- Los forms son objetos como cualquier otro objeto. La única diferencia notable, es que saben pintarse en una pantalla.. pero después, son exactamente iguales.
- Las instancias de los objetos están vivas mientras el padre que las creo, este vivo. Crear otra instancia, con el mismo nombre o la misma variable, no hace que sea lo mismo que antes.

Comment: Wow se nota que eres un pro respecto a esto, todos en nuestro salón estamos impresionados con tanta información que no sabemos por donde empezar.

Comment: -los terminos globales son usar statics?

Comment: -La de devolver un objeto a quien la llamó. como podría buscar ese tema en internet

Comment: Que base de datos recomiendas, estas requieren que el equipo siempre este conectado al wifi? Estoy super contento con tu respuesta, en realidad no pense que alguien fuera a contestar :))))))))))

Comment: Estás preguntando correctamente en SOes, fijo alguien responde, bienvenido a bordo :D

Comment: @fredyfx Graciass :))) :3

Comment: @kalvini tienes acceso al [chat]... Ahi hay mucha gente que puede contestar esta clase de dudas...

Comment: @gbianchi súper mil gracias, no sabía del chat te agradezco un mundo :)))